# 2 phase commit implementation

Tags: transactions, unique-key, document-database, 2phase-commit

I'm trying to implement a 2-phase commit over a document database which supports only single-phase commit using transaction info on the inserted data.

I understand the theory behind 2-phase commit, but in practice there are a few obstacles.

Let's say there is a collection with a unique ID defined, and the transaction includes updating several fields of a document.
So in order to save old data for the case of a rollback, I can't override the existing document, but need to add a new document and tag it with the transaction ID:

**Solution 1:**

Prepare phase:

1. Insert a new document to the main collection with the updated fields and mark it with the current transaction ID.
2. Mark the old document as deleted until committing and mark it with the current  transaction ID.

Commit phase:

1. Remove the transaction ID from the added (updated) document.
2. Delete the old document (which was marked as deleted)

Problem: part 1 of the prepare phase will fail since I'm adding another document with the same unique ID (although it's just for the sake of the transaction but it will still fail).

**Solution 2:**

Prepare phase:

1. Insert a new document to a *temporary* collection with the updated fields and mark it with the current transaction ID.
2. Mark the old document from the main collection as deleted until committing and mark it with the current transaction ID.

Commit phase:

1. Move the new document from the temporary collection to the main collection.
2. Delete the old document (which was marked as deleted) from the main collection.

Problem: Commit phase part 1 may fail if there is a unique key conflict when moving the document from the temporary collection to the main collection.
However I can't allow this error to occur during the commit phase, since it's too late, I would like a unique key constraint to fail during the prepare phase.

So what is the right way of implementing the 2 phase commit mechanism and avoid these issues?